# Check if Access Database Record Exists

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am using a VB program connected to an access database. In my code, I want to check if a record exists at the specified row, and if not, do something. Checking if the row exists is my issue. In pseudocode, this is what I want to achieve:

```
If RecordAtLocationExists = False Then
...
End If
```

Code I have tried includes:

```
If DBDataSet.Tables(TableName).Rows(QuestionNumber).IsNull = True Then

If DBDataSet.Tables(TableName).Rows(QuestionNumber) = "" Then

If DBDataSet.Tables(TableName).Rows(QuestionNumber) = Nothing Then

If DBDataSet.Tables(TableName).Rows(QuestionNumber) = Null Then
```

None of the above code works. I have tried to search for a solution, but everything else seems far too complicated for this. I am probably approaching this wrong, but hopefully it makes sense what I am trying to achieve.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what does it mean: _record exists at the specified row_?

Comment: 'RecordAtLocationExists' is obviously not VB, but pseudocode. For example, that could be DBDataSet.Tables(TableName).Rows(QuestionNumber) or something simpler like DataSet.TableName.Row(1). Make sense?

Comment: If you want to know how many rows exist you check the Rows.Count property (so QuestionNumber < Rows.Count then the row/record exists in your table. If you want to know if there is a value in a specific field of that row then you need to specify Rows(index).Item(FieldName/FieldIndex)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are trying to check if the record exists at a `DataTable`, not at database. Database data could have changed since you filled your `DataTable`. Try to query the database directly:

```
 Dim specificRow as Integer = 23  '<-- Set this variable to the specific row you are looking for
 Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE QuestionNumber = ?"   
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, myConnection)   
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("questionnumber", specificRow)
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

And test if the command return rows

```
If dr.Read() Then        
  ' Do stuff here
Else    
  ' Do another stuff here    
End if
```