# Avoid duplicate data using vb.net and ms access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

what can I use if I want to put a message box saying the data is already exist.
Here is my code.

Private Sub bttnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bttnSave.Click

```
    con.Open()
    Dim fname As String = Trim(txtFName.Text)
    Dim mname As String = Trim(txtMName.Text)
    Dim lname As String = Trim(txtLName.Text)
    Dim add As String = Trim(txtAddress.Text)
    Dim num As String = Trim(txtNumber.Text)
    Dim email As String = Trim(txtEmail.Text)
    Dim stat As String = "Active"
    Dim remark As String = "Available"

    If fname = Nothing Or mname = Nothing Or lname = Nothing Or add = Nothing Or num = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Please Fill All Fields", vbInformation, "Note")
    Else
        Dim add_guest As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblGuest(GuestFName,GuestMName,GuestLName,GuestAddress,GuestContactNumber,GuestGender,GuestEmail,Status,Remarks) values ('" &
                                          fname & "','" &
                                          mname & "','" &
                                          lname & "','" &
                                          add & "','" &
                                          num & "','" &
                                          cboGender.Text & "','" &
                                          email & "','" &
                                          stat & "','" &
                                          remark & "')", con)
        add_guest.ExecuteNonQuery()
        add_guest.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Guest Added!", vbInformation, "Note")
        txtFName.Clear()
        txtMName.Clear()
        txtLName.Clear()
        txtAddress.Clear()
        txtNumber.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
    End If
    con.Close()
    display_guest()
End Sub
```

Comment: You need a field that uniquely identity a person from another. Email or a social securiry number are usually good indicators of uniqueness. So you first try to read the database with that key and insert only if you don't find any match.

Comment: However you should first fix a bigger problem in your code. You concatenate strings to build an sql command. This will create a lot of problems here. Just to start try to insert a person with a single quote in its lastname like _O'Brian_ then search about Sql Injection

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @Steve said, add Primary or Unique key for tblGuest for column email. Then check the existence of the record before executing insert statement.

Primary key - [Add Primary key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-change-a-table-s-primary-key-in-access-07b4a84b-0063-4d56-8b00-65f2975e4379)

Check exists or not - [Check exists or not 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/448b2444-fe29-4efe-9666-6e9cb6ae77bb/vba-using-sql-exists-to-check-if-a-record-exists-in-a-table?forum=accessdev)

[Check exists or not 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491252/check-if-access-database-record-exists)